# Why is Firefox blocking my images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mozilla is blocking all images on just my index page. I have an image gallery on another page that pulls images from the same folder, and they show fine. I'm getting this in the console:

```
https://cdn.getforge.com/iof.getforge.io/1497635625/Resources/css/img/gallery/IO8.jpg [HTTP/2.0 403 Forbidden 54ms]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is blocking nothing.  Cloudfront is.  Check your config.

Comment: why do the images load in all browsers except IE and Firefox though?

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken They don't.  I just pulled it up in Chrome, and it doesn't load.  The `403` response code comes from the server.  Hit refresh, you probably have a cached image in your browser.

Comment: I disabled encryption and the images load now. Not sure what is causing the issue.